# Does increment operators e.g count++; stores volatile data thread-locally?

Tags: java

My goal is to understand how the volatile keyword works.

My expected result: The assertEquals did not fail.

My actual result: The assertEquals fail. (sometimes the actual count value are between 9991 to 9999).

**I am assuming this happens because of the increment operators / `count++` equals to**

```
public void increment() {
  int temp = count;
  count = temp + 1;
}
```

and considering that, the `temp` attribute is stored thread-locally. Am I true?

Counter.java

```
public class Counter implements Runnable {
  private volatile int count = 0;
  public int getCount() { return count; }
  public void increment() { count++; }
  @Override
  public void run() { increment(); }
}
```

CounterTest.java

```
public class CounterTest {
  @Test
  void increment() {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    Counter counter = new Counter();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      service.execute(counter);
    }
    service.shutdown();
    service.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    assertEquals(10000, counter.getCount());
  }
}
```

Comment: `count++;` is _not_ atomic, period. `volatile` is not about atomicity, but visibility, only.

Comment: Yes, your assumption is basically right. Read the variable, update the value, store the value. Two threads may do the first two steps before either does the 3rd step, resulting in an increment going missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My goal is to understand how the volatile keyword works

If that is your goal, then start looking at the `JLS` and the guarantees that `volatile` offers. `volatile` is *not* about atomic operations, i.e.: `count++;` is not atomic. As such, this :

```
assertEquals(10000, counter.getCount());
```

can fail, at any point in time.

`volatile` is about what some thread is supposed to "observe" when it has observed a written value to that variable, by another thread. There are many, *literally many* examples of what this means, probably the most famous one  [is this](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html). Start there and build your knowledge up to the `JLS`.